# Google Analytics - Python API

Tags: python, syntax, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using Python to extract data from Google Analytics API,
I use dimensionFilterClauses for filtering out specific value, does anyone know what is the operator for such filter? (the opposite of 'Exact')

Here is the example of the working Exact:

```
"dimensionFilterClauses": [
{
  "filters": [
      {
       "dimensionName": "ga:eventCategory",
       "operator": "EXACT",
       "expressions": ["Operational Events"]
}]}],
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to filter out events by their category, I believe you just need to add the "not" field:

```
"dimensionFilterClauses": [
{
  "filters": [
      {
       "dimensionName": "ga:eventCategory",
       "operator": "EXACT",
       "not": "true",
       "expressions": ["Operational Events"]
}]}],
```

Comment: @ArielYosef If it worked, consider accepting their answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are the following options for [`operator`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#operator):

- `OPERATOR_UNSPECIFIED`    If the match type is unspecified, it is treated as a REGEXP.
- `REGEXP`  The match expression is treated as a regular expression. All match types are not treated as regular expressions.
- `BEGINS_WITH` Matches the value which begin with the match expression provided.
- `ENDS_WITH`   Matches the values which end with the match expression provided.
- `PARTIAL` Substring match.
- `EXACT`   The value should match the match expression entirely.
- `NUMERIC_EQUAL` - Integer comparison filters. case sensitivity is ignored for these and the expression is assumed to be a string representing an integer. Failure conditions:

  - If expression is not a valid int64, the client should expect an error.
  - Input dimensions that are not valid int64 values will never match the filter.
- `NUMERIC_GREATER_THAN` - Checks if the dimension is numerically greater than the match expression. Read the description for NUMERIC_EQUALS for restrictions.
- `NUMERIC_LESS_THAN`   Checks if the dimension is numerically less than the match expression. Read the description for NUMERIC_EQUALS for restrictions.
- `IN_LIST` 
  This option is used to specify a dimension filter whose expression can take any value from a selected list of values. This helps avoiding evaluating multiple exact match dimension filters which are OR'ed for every single response row. For example:

  - expressions: `["A", "B", "C"]` - Any response row whose dimension has it is value as A, B or C, matches this DimensionFilter.